# Barba.js - Custom CSS transition doesn’t work

Tags: barbajs

I’m importing @barba/core and @barba/css as intended but i cant get barba to work with custom CSS classes.

```
// tell Barba to use the css module
barba.use(barbaCss);

// init Barba
barba.init({
    transitions:[{
        name: 'custom-transition',
    }]
});
```

If my understanding of the documentation is right, barba should add `.custom-transition-appear-active` to the barba wrapper. But barba still uses the basic `.barba-appear-active` class.

Any ideas on this ?

Comment: By the way i’m using [@barba/css]  2.1.9 and [@barba/core]  2.3.12. I’m also using the default wrappers.

Comment: https://github.com/barbajs/barba/issues/422#issuecomment-511707789